# React native app BUILD FAILED after installing @react-native-firebase/app

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, push-notification

app BUILD FAILED  after i install @react-native-firebase/app

package.json

```
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.0",
```

this is my build.gradle

```
    implementation project(':react-native-pusher-push-notifications') 
    implementation 'com.pusher:push-notifications-android:1.9.0'

        implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.1.0")
    implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.0")
      implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'  // <-- ADD THIS DEPENDENCY
```

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdu found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.1.1-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.1.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-sdk-api-21.3.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:21.3.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdv found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.1.1-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.1.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-sdk-api-21.3.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:21.3.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdw found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.1.1-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.1.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-sdk-api-21.3.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:21.3.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdx found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.1.1-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.1.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-sdk-api-21.3.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:21.3.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdy found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.1.1-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.1.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-sdk-api-21.3.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:21.3.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdz found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.1.1-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.1.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-sdk-api-21.3.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:21.3.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzea found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.1.1-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.1.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-sdk-api-21.3.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:21.3.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzeb found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.1.1-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-
```

Answer (score 0):

android / app / build.gradle

add this

```
def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())

allprojects {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            // Remove this override in 0.65+, as a proper fix is included in react-native itself.
            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
        }
    }
     repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven { // <---- Add this block
            url 'https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-maven-repository/raw/master/releases'
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you but it is not working i add my build.gradle so you can check it

Comment: this is error is go away after i remove this package 
"react-native-pusher-push-notifications": "^2.5.2",

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem

with this package    "react-native-pusher-push-notifications": "^2.5.2",

so what i do is install an older version from firebase

so i replace this  "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.0.0", with "@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.12.0",

and now everything is working fine